# How to create a conditional statement for in RxJs where the condition is the result of another observable?

Tags: rxjs, ngrx

In the code below I am trying to set 'this.organizationRequests$' to it's initial value OR when the actionSubject returns a CreateNewOrganizationRequest type set 'this.organizationRequests$' to null. How to set an alternative route for the ofType ?

Pseudo code:

```
    this.organizationRequests$ = this.organizationRequests$.pipe(
      filter(orgRequest => Boolean(orgRequest)),
      switchMap(orgRequest =>
        this.actionSubject.pipe(
          ofType(fromOrgActions.CreateNewOrganizationRequests)
        )
          ? EMPTY
          : of(orgRequest)
      )
    );
```

Comment: What's wrong with that you have right now?

Comment: it only returns an EMPTY when ofType(fromOrgActions.CreateNewOrganizationRequests), but i need the alternative route too for when this is false - of(orgRequest) is never returned

Comment: I'm confused. ofType is a filter for NgRx actions no? It doesn't return a boolean value. How long do you want to wait for actionSubject  to emit a value before you decide to emit its initial value?